# Post-nuclear-war book involving motorcycle-riding blind teenagers and a former US president at Cheyenne Mt

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

I read a post-nuclear-war book in the early 90's. The only two parts I remember are there were almost totally blind people in Denver riding motorcycles, and Cheyenne Mountain was destroyed, and a former US President was there.

I believe the blind people were teenagers.  They were riding from their building, down the hill to another, where other people had something they wanted.

The President at Cheyenne Mt was on a ledge on the outside and came to a door, hanging off the hinges, with a wheel type door lock like on a submarine.

It is not *Swan Song*, *Lucifer's Hammer*, or *The Lost Traveller*.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: You might also mention that you've [asked the question elsewhere](http://forums.abebooks.de/discussions/AbeBookscom_BookSleuthreg/Science_Fiction/Book_TitleAuthor/abesleuthcom/37302.1?redirCnt=1&nav=messages). I find it difficult to believe that you've remembered no additional detail after having thought about it for 20+ days